# Ruby on Rails: Subquerying an array of found objects' relational objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have a model Profile that has a onetoone with the model Interest. If I query an array of Profiles using where, how would I then get another separate array composed of the Interests associated with those originally queried Profiles?

Something like

```
@foundProfiles = Profile.where(field: data)
```

into

```
@foundInterests = @foundProfiles.Interest.all
```

this doesn't work, but that's the idea I'm trying to get at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of association:

```
@foundProfiles = Profile.includes(:interest).where(field: data)
# Eager load interest to avoid n + 1 queries

@foundInterests = @foundProfiles.map(&:interest)
```

**EDIT**

If you need to query further on the `Interest` records you can do something like:

```
@foundInterests = Interest.where(profile_id: @foundProfiles.map(&:id))
```

This will return you `Interest` records associated with `@foundProfiles` and you can chain `where` on it

Comment: Thanks, I was in the dark about the map function.

Comment: It seems as though I can't do a follow up where on @foundInterests though... it gives me a no method where error

Comment: No you can't. it will return you array

Comment: Okay then. If I did a query of Interests, how would I then do another query (using some criteria) on the Profiles associated with those Interests? So that my final result is an array of desired Profiles? This is a slight reversal of the original question in terms of objects, but the key question is a the same. How would I do a query, and then do another query of the *associated* objects?

Comment: You can use `ids`

Comment: How so? Manually write a for loop that iterates over the array of intially queried Interests, taking the interest id, using that id to do a find_by on Profile, and then just add that onto a new array? Is there a more eloquent way of doing this, maybe using built in methods?